# Android System Webview 51.0.2704.81 update make my Ionic app to crash

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-webview, crosswalk-runtime

since the latest ASW update, my Ionic app is not launching anymore so I had to manually uninstall all updates to make it work again. Anyone has experienced the same?
I re-considering to use xwalk but I don't like the size issue though.. my app increase from 30mb to 100 with it ...